# Store texture for drag-control

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, vertex

again openGL) I need to make drag-control for textures and don't know how to store this values. i have a struct with point, image for texture, but i need a texture to change their position, so i need to change glVertex2f on mousePressed method, as i understand

```
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //enable 2D texturing
if(number < 4){
   glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
} else {
   glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
}

glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2f(x/window_width, y/window_height);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2f(x/window_width+0.2, y/window_height);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2f(x/window_width+0.2, y/window_height+0.2);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2f(x/window_width, y/window_height+0.2);
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

how can i add them to vector and then change position ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag the texture, you need to change the `glTextCoord2d` values.
This way the poligon remains fixed but the texture you apply to it shifts.

Also check out the texture [params](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) to apply warp to your texture so that it repeats.

Comment: Thanks, i understand about changing position, i need to know how to create object with this params, that in future i can make something like 
obj->glVertex2f(0.1,0.2) e.t.c.

Comment: @gronzzz: Have your object class have a member `putVertex` that either calls `glVertex` with the right parameters. Or better let it fill into an array you can pass to OpenGL as a vertex array. glVertex and its friends are obsolete and have been removed from modern OpenGL altogether.